# Non nested div position

Tags: html, css

How do I position the blocks like a org chart? For example Susan comes in the top row, Joe & Rob in second row etc. Do I have to define a class for every element and define the position like secondlevel1{position:absolute;left:100px} etc. Since I don't have parent child divs here, I am not sure how to position the elements.

```css
.EmployeeInfo{
 width:120px;
height:20px;
border:2px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="EmployeeInfo secondlevel1">Joe</div>
<div class="EmployeeInfo">David</div>
<div class="EmployeeInfo">Amy</div>
<div class="EmployeeInfo">Paul</div>
<div class="EmployeeInfo toplevel">Susan</div>
<div class="EmployeeInfo secondlevel2">Rob</div>
```

Comment: do you have any example that you can show us how you want to make this ?

Comment: If you make an org chart like this then yes, you'll have to use `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` for each box to place them where you want. There are lots of libraries out there for making org charts for websites, you should do a google search for them.

Comment: Tyler, Thank you for your answer. I am not creating the html here. This is a sample html generated from another application.